# Problema Array to String Conversion

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo una clase para `Codeigniter` con una propiedad `$keywords` que quiero asignar con la función `set_keywords()`

```
class Seo
{

    private $keywords = array();


    public function set_keywords($keywords)
    {
        $this->$keywords = $keywords;
    }
}
```

Y en mi controlador:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('seo');
    $keywords = array('hola','mundo');
    $this->seo->set_keywords($keywords);

    $this->load->view('inicio_view');
}
```

Me da el error

> Array to string conversion

Y no tengo ni idea de cual es el problema.

Comment: tienes otra parte dentro del código donde utilices `$keywords` o el método? muéstranos la linea y el error donde ocurre lo que planteas, probé tu código y no muestra ningún error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El posible error que encuentro en su código que no tiene que ver solamente con `Codeigniter` si no con `PHP` en general y con `POO`,

Está intentando acceder al atributo incorrectamente , ya que para acceder a la propiedad debería ser sin el signo `$` el nombre de la propiedad,  ya que este signo `$`  es para representar variables en `PHP`.

```
class Seo
{
    private $keywords = array();
    public function set_keywords($keywords)
    {
        $this->keywords = $keywords;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Vaya error mas tonto... XD

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo esta claro, tienes el código de la vista de casualidad?, trata de imprimir en él en la biblioteca seo

```
class Seo{

private $keywords = array();


public function set_keywords($keywords)
{
    $this->$keywords = $keywords;
    var_dump($this->$keywords);
    die;


}
```

y comenta si pasa la variable y como la imprime, el problema puede ser que no estas pasando los datos a la vista en el controlador debería ser algo como

`$datos['keywords'] =  $this->seo->set_keywords($keywords); 
 $this->load->view('inicio_view',$datos);`
pensando en que lo que hace tu biblioteca es una manipulación de datos